# $and query in mongo db with @Query annotation not working in spring data jpa

Tags: spring, mongodb, jpa, spring-data-jpa, crud-repository

I am developing one application based on spring boot with jpa repository in it for the **mongo** **database**. I am using below annotation with **query**

**@Query("{'$and':[ {'characteristics.name':?0}, {'characteristics.value':?1} ]}")**

```
@Repository
public interface ResourceRepository extends MongoRepository<Resource, String> {

    @Query("{'$and':[ {'characteristics.name':?0}, {'characteristics.value':?1} ]}")
    Optional<Resource> findResourceByMacAddressWithValue(String macAddress, String value);

}
```

my Resource object looks like this :

```
@Document(collection = "resource")
@Data
@Slf4j
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Resource extends BaseAuditer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String type;
    private List<ResourceCharacteristics> characteristics;
}
```

and ResourceCharacteristics looks like this :

```
@Data
@Slf4j
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ResourceCharacteristics {

    private String name;
    private String value;

}
```

My goal is to use find resource if that resource has some particular name and with some value...so I am using above **and** query but it is working like **or** query when I tested, I wanted to make it work like **and** query only.

anybody can help me in this what's wrong that I am doing in this query annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `$and`

```
@Query("{characteristics.name: ?0, characteristics.value: ?1}")
```

Comment: ,I have already tried without ```$and``` but no luck